# Serialize and deserialize json c#

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to build a json (with success) but now i need to deserialize the json, it's the first time i'm using json so i don't really know what do to. I got that's exception when i try to deserialize:

`` Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Boosty.AltsInfos[]]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path '', line 1, position 1. ``

- Serializer:

  ```
  var json = new List<Alts>();
  List<AltsInfos> p1 = new List<AltsInfos> { new AltsInfos { alts_name = "JeSaisPas", alts_email = "truc2fou@g.com", alts_pass = "azerty", alts_type = AltsInfos.AltType.Microsoft } };
            json.Add(new Alts { account = p1 });
            List<AltsInfos> p2 = new List<AltsInfos> { new AltsInfos { alts_name = "TrucBidule", alts_email = "trucmachun@g.com", alts_pass = "azerty2.0", alts_type = AltsInfos.AltType.Microsoft } };
            json.Add(new Alts { account = p2 });

            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
            File.WriteAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"/BoostyLauncher" + @"/alts.json", jsonString);
  ```
- Deserializer

  ```
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"/BoostyLauncher" + @"/alts.json"))
            {
                string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
                List<AltsInfos> alts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AltsInfos>>(json);
                foreach (var item in alts)
                    Console.WriteLine(item.alts_email);
   }
  ```
- Type containers

  ```
  class Alts
  {
    public List<AltsInfos> account { get; set; }
  }
   class AltsInfos
   {
    public string alts_name { get; set; }
    public string alts_email { get; set; }
    public string alts_pass { get; set; }
    public AltType alts_type { get; set; }

    public enum AltType
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "Microsoft")]
        Microsoft,
        [EnumMember(Value = "Altening")]
        Altening
    }
  }
  ```

All i want is to extract **alts_name** for each **account** category. Also i don't know how i set the enum in the json it's set to 0.

```
[
  {
    "account": [
      {
        "alts_name": "JeSaisPas",
        "alts_email": "truc2fou@g.com",
        "alts_pass": "azerty",
        "alts_type": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "account": [
      {
        "alts_name": "TrucBidule",
        "alts_email": "trucmachun@g.com",
        "alts_pass": "azerty2.0",
        "alts_type": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: The error message that you posted is pretty clear: Your json is a list and you are trying to deserialize it to a dictionary. Declare you variable as List when deserializing, or change your json object.

Comment: You serialized an *array* of `Alts` objects but try to deserialize it as a `Dictionary<string,AltsInfos[]>`. There's no way this can work. The JSON string doesn't contain a dictionary, it contains an array. Use the correc type instead, `JsonSerializer.DeserializeObject<Alts[]>(json)`

Comment: Is there a reason the question shouldn't be closed as a typo?

Comment: I just deserialize and not seem to work. I get white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix  a bug in your deserialize code. Instead of List< AltsInfos > use List< Alts >

```
List<Alts> alts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Alts>>(jsonString);

foreach (var alt in alts)
           foreach (var item in alt.account)
              Console.WriteLine(item.alts_email);
```

or you can use LINQ

```
List<string> emails = alts.SelectMany(a => a.account.Select(s => s.alts_email)).ToList();
```

and BTW if you want a json string to be indented, fix the serializer options too

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes in deserialized line.
**should always deserialze into same class (which serialized into json) that is List< Alts >.**

```
var json = new List<Alts>();
   List<AltsInfos> p1 = new List<AltsInfos> { new AltsInfos { alts_name = "JeSaisPas", alts_email = "truc2fou@g.com", alts_pass = "azerty", alts_type = AltType.Microsoft } };
   json.Add(new Alts { account = p1 });
   List<AltsInfos> p2 = new List<AltsInfos> { new AltsInfos { alts_name = "TrucBidule", alts_email = "trucmachun@g.com", alts_pass = "azerty2.0", alts_type = AltType.Microsoft } };
   json.Add(new Alts { account = p2 });

   string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
   **List<Alts>** alts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<**List<Alts>**>(jsonString);
```

Please let me know if it solve your problem otherwise will try to explain more.